# Where can I find the data points for the Insights chart in the Facebook dashboard?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am currently using the Open Graph API but am not opposed to using FQL if it can get me the data points I'd like.  Right now I am just hitting the urls directly and not worrying about a client SDK.

Of the three charts on http://www.facebook.com/insights/ => websites I can find the data for the Site Engagement chart in the Domain Insights in the API.

However, I can't seem to find the points for Distribution on Facebook, or Referral Traffic to Site in the insight data being returned for the domain.  Did I miss them, are they available maybe in FQL or are they just not exposed yet?

Edit: It looks like someone doesn't understand what charts I am talking about so to clarify, I am looking for the following anywhere in the Open Graph API, FQL, or anyplace else in Facebook:

- Like Story Impressions
- Share Story Impressions
- Like Story Clicks
- Share Story Clicks

Answer (score 0):

This info is now available via the Insights app.  News Feed section has some of it, at least the story impressions and clicks.